# Eldritch Smite: Can you decide whether the enemy goes prone or do they always go prone?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, warlock, conditions, eldritch-invocations

> Once per turn when you hit a creature with your pact weapon, you can
> expend a warlock spell slot to deal an extra 1d8 force damage to the
> target, plus another 1d8 per level of the spell slot, and you can
> knock the target prone if it is Huge or smaller.

Since it says "**can** knock the target prone." I assumed it was optional, (though you wouldn't have much reason not to if in melee, within 5 ft.)

Comment: Aside: prone targets grant advantage to attacks from within 5 feet, and impose disadvantage on attacks from farther that 5 feet away, so knocking down targets may annoy your ranged allies.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

#### Knocking the target prone is optional.

You have understood the feature correctly. "Can" indicates that you are *able to*, but does not indicate that you are compelled to.

If the prone-knocking were not optional, it would read something like:

> and the target is knocked prone if it is huge or smaller.

This is similar to the language used in many features which knock targets prone. For example, the spell [*destructive wave*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/destructive-wave) (PHB, pg. 231) says:

> Each creature you choose within 30 feet of you must succeed on a Constitution saving throw or take 5d6 thunder damage, as well as 5d6 radiant or necrotic damage (your choice), *and be knocked prone.*

The spell description states what happens - targets are knocked prone when they fail the save, and it is not optional.